# Как осуществить последовательность выполнения скрипта в jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция showItems, которая получает все товары из БД вставляет их на страницу покупок в виде последовательных картинок с описанием, есть вторая функция checkMyItems, которая получает из бд id товаров, которые выбрал пользователь. Товары предчтавляют собой div-элемент с каринкой на background. Проблема в том, что раз через раз выполянется вторая функция быстрее первой и все начинает визуально ломаться. Как сделать так чтобы мы были уверены, что первый скрипт полностью отработан и подгрузил все картинки?

Пробывал так, но проблема осталась:

```
$.when(showItems()).then(checkMyItems());

function showItems(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "shop.php",
            data: {
                Action: "getItems"
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
                //вставляем items 
...
}); 
}
```

Comment: что возвращает функция showItems?

Comment: можно часть функции `showItems`?

Comment: Функция ничего не возвращает просто получает данные по ajax и вставляет через each в нужные места

Comment: в вопрос добавь ее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) возвращает deffered объект, у которого есть функция `then`. Поэтому в данном случае не нужен `when`, достаточно вернуть из функции *showItems* результат выполнения `$.ajax`.

```
function showItems(){ return $.ajax(...) }
```

Далее добавить обработчик через функцию `then`

```
showItems().then(checkMyItems);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!